# Accessibility settings - WCAG2

Tags: accessibility, wcag2.0

Is an accessibility button **required** on the site?

Or is it possible to link to a page that contains accessibility settings in menu or footer? (instead of a fixed floated button)

And if so mandatory - where should the button be located?

Comment: Are you able to clarify what you mean by `accessibility button`?

Comment: @ksav: like there is in many websites, a floated fixed button that open a menu of acessibility settings like change contrast or font size

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: By the way, are you referring to WCAG 2.0 (published in December 2008) or WCAG 2.1 (published in June 2018)? Both are currently valid W3C recommendations, but WCAG 2.1 added a few new requirements.

Answer (score 3):

The "accessibility button" mentioned in this question refers to a button at the top of a web page that opens a number of accessibility settings. See for example

- "show preferences" on [GPII.net](https://gpii.net/). This uses [UI Options](https://docs.fluidproject.org/infusion/development/UserInterfaceOptionsAPI.html).
- The [ATBar](https://www.atbar.org/) developed at the University of Southampton.
- [Dyxlexia Cornwall](https://www.dyslexiacornwall.org.uk/am-i-dyslexic/) uses [Recite](http://www.reciteme.com/user-guide) (commercial)

Some sites have buttons for specific aspects:

- The A+ and A- buttons and the "eye" button on the website of the [European Blind Union](http://www.euroblind.org/).
- The buttons for text size and contrast on the website of the [European Disability Forum](http://www.edf-feph.org/).
- The options for "Kontrast" (contrast) and "Schriftgröße" (font size) at [Stuttgart.de](https://www.stuttgart.de/).

The W3C's Web Accessibility Initiative also has a "Change Text Size or Colors" link at the top of the page. However, this link does not open a panel or other UI interface for changing font size and colours, but instead takes you to a page that explains to users how to do these things in their own browser.

This in itself does not prove that WCAG 2.1 does not require this type of buttons (WCAG 2.1 was published in June 2018 and WAI just might not have updated its website yet), but it is easy to find where WCAG requires a specific technique or process. When searching for the term "mechanism" in [WCAG 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/), one encounters one success criterion that is about the visual presentation of text: [SC 1.4.8 at level AAA](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#visual-presentation). This requires among other things, that

> (...) a mechanism is available to achieve the following:
>
> - Foreground and background colors can be selected by the user.
>   (...)
> - Text can be resized without assistive technology up to 200 percent in a way that does not require the user to scroll horizontally to read a line of text on a full-screen window.

The last requirement (text resizing) can usually be achieved with appropriate CSS rules; the user can use the browser to do the resizing (e.g. using the buttons `Ctrl` & `+`). The first requirement is something that can be done in *some* browsers (Mozilla Firefox) but not in all (e.g. Chrome and Opera; in Internet Explorer, you need to be able to write user style sheets). This means that web developers cannot count on browsers to provide this mechanism, so it needs to be provided by the web content, e.g. in the form of an accessible (!) button at the top of the page. See also technique [G175: Providing a multi color selection tool on the page for foreground and background colors](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G175.html).

The above-mentioned button would only be required if the site must conform to level AAA, which is rarely the case. Legal requirements don't go beyond level AA because level AAA cannot apply to all sites (due to the nature of some of the success criteria at that level).

The mechanism or button needs to conform to all the success criteria at the level of the conformance claim (see [definition of mechanism](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#dfn-mechanism)). In this case, the button would need to meet all success criteria in WCAG 2.1 (all three levels). It would need to be at the top of the page or at the start of the tabbing order, although this would be beneficial to user who need this mechanism.

Comment: thank u very much! still have my question - if I want to provide a menu of accessibility settings, do they required to be positioned in a button at the top of the page (that will be the first focused element by the tab key) or all of this settings can be located in a different document that will be linked from the menu or from the footer of each document in the site?

Comment: @BIBI According to the SC, it would not need to be at the "start" of the page, but it would need to meet all WCAG 2.1 criteria (AAA) if the site claims conformance to WCAG 2.1 Level AAA. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most accessibility laws refer to Level AA of WCAG, and if you are constrained to that, then the simple answer is "no", an "accessibility button" is not specifically required by WCAG.  If you follow the guidelines in WCAG, then your site will be usable by the greatest number of people.

For example, [1.4.4 Resize Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-scale.html).  If you design your site so that if the user uses the browser's increase font feature (typically <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>), and your page reflows properly so that text does not overlap or clip, then you're good.  You don't have to provide a button that increases the font.

For color issues, [1.4.1 Use of Color](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-without-color.html) and [1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum)](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html), again, if you follow the guidelines, then you're good.  1.4.1 doesn't say that color can't be used, but that color itself cannot be the **only** means to indicate meaning.  For example, if you had a table of values and if values between a certain range were red, that would violoate 1.4.1.  However, if values were red **and** bold, or italic, or had parens around them or an asterisk, or anything in addition to being red, then you'd conform with 1.4.1

For 1.4.3, just make sure your text color has a color ratio of 4.5:1 compared to the background color.  (It can be 3:1 for "larger" text).  If so, then again, you're ok.  You do not need to provide a button that changes the text color or provide different color themes.

That doesn't mean you can't provide a button that allows font resizing or color themes, but it's not required.  And as @ChristopheStrobbe said, if you're trying to achieve Level AAA of WCAG (which is rare), then you **would** have to provide some way to change some of these settings (1.4.8)

Comment: Great answer!! thank u so much. but I still have my question, if my site is not fully design by the wcag rules and I need to provide a button to offer the options like contrast etc. does it have to be by a button at the top of each document, or is it could be as a link to a accessibility settings page in the footer or in the side menu?

Comment: You are free to implement it any way you want.  WCAG is a set of guidelines that is technology agnostic.  They can be applied to any technology (html, native mobile apps, desktop apps, kiosks, etc).   Because of this, WCAG is not going to tell you how to implement something.  It just says "Foreground and background colors can be selected by the user".  It's something you should discuss with a UX person.  Granted, having it early on the page is probably nice from a user experience perspective, but it's not required.

Comment: One other thing, you said "*if my site is not fully design by the wcag rules and I need to provide a button to offer the options...*", providing a button to change these things will **not** make your site compliant to WCAG.  That is, if your site doesn't follow 1.4.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.3 as mentioned above (among other WCAG success criteria), then providing a button to change these settings does not satisfy these previous success criteria.  It **will** satisfy 1.4.8 but you still need to comply with the other rules. So you can't use this "accessibility button" as an excuse to not do the other work.